# SQL Query finding averages

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Find movies where their fans are less than the average number of fans for that specific genre

```
fan (fID: integer, fName: string)
movies(mID: integer, mName: string, mGenre: string, mYear: integer)
like(fID: integer, mID: integer)
```

Foreign Keys:

```
(like.fID -> fan.fID)
(like.mID-.> movie.mID)
```

I tried doing this to get the average number of fans for each movie and it didn't work:

```
SELECT mGenre, AVG(total)
FROM findAverage, movies
GROUP BY mGenre;

CREATE VIEW findAverage AS
SELECT m.mName, COUNT(DISTINCT L.fID) as total
FROM like L, movies m
WHERE L.mID = B.mID 
GROUP BY m.mName
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter your view to include the `mId` field.  Then you can use this field to `JOIN` your view back to the `movies` table.

```
CREATE VIEW findAverage AS
SELECT L.mId, m.mName, COUNT(DISTINCT L.fID) as total
FROM like L
    INNER JOIN movies m ON L.mID = B.mID 
GROUP BY L.mId, m.mName
```

And then to get the averages per genre:

```
SELECT m.mGenre, AVG(f.total)
FROM findAverage f
    INNER JOIN movies m ON f.mId = m.mId
GROUP BY m.mGenre
```

Comment: how can I get the output as movieID, and movieName for movies that have less fans than average fans of movies of that respective genre. For example if action genre has 100 fans average per movie, and Rambo has 89 fans, and Rocky has 105 fans, I just want to get Rambo and Rambo's movie iD in output. Thanks again for your help